# SQL Server CE - Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database that works fine in dev, but when installed on the client has an issue.

- The SQL Server CE 3.5 dependencies are copied as part of the deployment.
- The target machine is a clean Windows 7 32-bit Ultimate image.

The message for the exception in the event log is:

```
Message: Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region. 
Stack Trace: at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) at
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent) at
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() at
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) at
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(
    Expression query, 
    QueryInfo queryInfo,
    IObjectReaderFactory factory, 
    Object[] parentArgs, 
    Object[] userArgs,
    ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, 
    Object lastResult) at
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(
    Expression query, 
    QueryInfo[] queryInfos,
    IObjectReaderFactory factory, 
    Object[] userArguments, 
    ICompiledSubQuery[]
    subQueries) at
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(
    Expression query) at
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() at 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
Application specific stuff here
```

It looks like this is [SSCE_M_CANTOPENSHAREDMEMORY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171879.aspx) and the site says there isn't a connection string value to change this and that these issues are typically not resolvable by the end developers.

Has anyone run into this, and if so were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: So when I install the CE runtime instead of doing the file copy there is no issue.

Answer (score 8):

You're right that the CE runtime has to be installed. And if you're using VS2010, you have to make sure that you install SP2 of the CE runtimes.

Even with that installed, I've run into this. In my case, I had a SQL Server CE instance acting as a local cache for a database using ADO.NET Synchronization Services. Is this your scenario?

I found that on test machines I got this error:

- If the platform was Vista or Windows
  7; and
- If the SQL Server CE database    was
  installed with the application to
  reside in a protected directory, such
  as C:\Program Files or C:\Program
  Files (x86); and
- If the program was    run using
  standard user credentials    (i.e.
  not escalated to Administrator)

Workarounds for the condition included:

- Running the application "as
  Administrator"; or
- Configuring the application manifest to require Administrator credentials; or
- Refactoring the application so that the .sdf file was located in an unprotected directory, such as C:\ProgramData[some subdirectory name] and modifying the connection string to point to that area; or
- Relocating the entire application directory in a user space. For instance, in "Documents" or some similar space with full file access rights to the EXE and the .SDF file

  Obviously, each of those options has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Windows 7.

It was because the user was in a Domain and the permissions where granted to "Everyone" and failed.

It must be granted to %DOMAIN%/Everyone

regards