# Installer c# windows form app/sdf database

Tags: c#, installation, sql-server-ce

I did a c# windows form app that uses a local `.sdf` database (SQL Server Compact Edition) but I can't create an installer for that.

I use the setup wizard from Visual Studio but the intalled program gives me an unhandled exception error. I don't know if the error is the connection string or other.

My problem is not access the .sfd database but create a setup in order to install the application in other computers. To create an installer project I used the setup wizard project of visual studio 2010 but when I install the application using the generated setup the program does not run. My problem is that I don't know how to create a setup for my application. The connection string is "Data Source = |DataDirectory|DataBase\yyyy.sdf" in the app.config. I don't have any code for the installer.

Comment: Sure, someone can help you, if you show us some code.

Comment: You keep coming back to the installer, but obviously you have a run time problem in your app, not the installer. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find that out please show us your code, but at least wrap your DB methods in a try-catch block:

```
try
{
  // do your DB stuff here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Without having seen your code, check that you don't hard code paths to the .sdf as an example.
Further, are you distributing all the [required dependencies for SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174138%28v=sql.105%29)?
Remember to not install the .sdf in the program files Folder, as it violates Window's user Access model.

Comment: My problem is not access the .sfd database but create a setup in order to install the application in other computers. To create an installer project I used the setup wizard project of visual studio 2010 but when I install the application using the generated setup the program does not run.

My problem is that I don't know how to create a setup for my application. The connection string is "Data Source = |DataDirectory|DataBase\yyyy.sdf" in the app.config. I don't have any code for the installer.

Comment: I don't believe you have any problems with the installer, although you keep coming back to it again and again. If I read you correctly, you experience problems when you actually run the application after the fact that it is installed, right? In that case, the installer has done its part of the deal. Leave it. Now, to determine what kind of problem you have in your application once it's installed, please do what I have suggested in my answer and re-package and re-install the application and see what the MessageBox will reveal to you.

Comment: I did what you said and the message is: "Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region"

Comment: I think the problem is the permission on the folder, I change permission manually and the app run. I have to found a way to give permission on install.

Comment: Where do you put the .sdf file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791345/sqlce-4-ef4-1-internal-error-cannot-open-the-shared-memory-region  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571847/sql-server-ce-internal-error-cannot-open-the-shared-memory-region