# Cannot open the shared memory region error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I have a user reporting this error when they're using my application.

The application is a .NET Winforms application running on Windows XP Embedded, using SQL Server CE 3.5 sp1, and Linq-To-SQL as the ORM. The database itself is located in a subdirectory my application creates in the `My Documents` folder. The user account is an adminstrator account on the system. There are no other applications or processes connecting to the database.

For the most part, the application seems to run fine. It starts up, can load data from and save data to the database. The user is using the application to access the database maybe a couple hundred times a day. They get this error, but only intermittently. Maybe 3-4 times a day.

In the code itself, all of the calls to the database are using a Linq-To-SQL data context that's wrapped in a `using` clause. So in other words:

```
using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(ConnectionString))
{
     List<blah> someList = db.SomeTable.Where(//selection criteria).ToList();

     return(someList);
}
```

That's what pretty much all of the calls to the database look like (with the exception that the ones that save data obviously aren't selecting and returning anything). As I mentioned before, they have no issue 99% of the time but only get the shared memory error a few times a day.

My current "fix" is on application startup I simply read all of the data out of the database (there's not a lot) and cache it in memory and converted my database calls to read from the in-memory lists. So far, this seems to have fixed the problem.  For a day and a half now they've reported no problems. But this is still bugging me, because I don't know what would cause the error in the first place.

While the application is accessing the database a few hundred times a day, it's typically not in rapid-fire succession. It's usually once every few minutes at the least. However, there is one use-case where there might be two calls one right after the other, as fast as possible. In other words, something like:

```
//user makes a selectio n on the screen
DatabaseCall1();
DatabaseCall2();
```

Both of those would follow the pattern in the code block above where they create a new context, do work, and then return. But these calls aren't asynchronous, so I would expect the connection would be closed and disposed of before DatabaseCall2 is invoked. However, could it be that something on the SQL Server CE end isn't closing the connection fast enough? It might explain why it's intermittent since maybe most of the time it doesn't have a problem? I should also mention that this exact program without the fix is installed on a few other systems with the exact same hardware and software (they're clones of each other), and users of the other systems have not reported any errors.

I'm stuck scratching my head because I can't reproduce this error on my development machine or a test machine, and answers to questions about this exception here and other places typically revolve around insufficient user permissions or the database on a shared network folder.

Comment: Does the user in question have the database file open i  another app/Tool (with a different connection string) ? Or does your app use several diffrent (letter by letter) connection strings?

Answer (score 0):

Check this previous post,I think you will find your answer :-

[SQL Server CE - Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571847/sql-server-ce-internal-error-cannot-open-the-shared-memory-region)